# Updating JLabel content through another class not working

Tags: java, inheritance, jlabel, updating, jcomponent

I am running into a problem with the following code. I have a BluePrint class which contains a button and a label. I have a Change class which inherits everything form the BluePrint class.

I have another class NewText, which contains a **setNewText()** method. The idea is to update the label content in the Change class through the use of the NewText class, by clicking the button in the Change class. However for some reason the setText method (in setNewText) does not seem to work.
If on the other hand I change the mouseclick method in the Change class to the below code, it seems to work.

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            lblTest.setText("Updated");
        }
```

Do you guys know what the reason is? The code is below

**BluePrint.java**

```
public class BluePrint {

public JFrame frame;
JLabel lblTest = new JLabel("Test");
JButton btnUpdate = new JButton("Update");
/**
 * @wbp.parser.entryPoint
 */
public void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(frame.getContentPane());
    groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(183)
                        .addComponent(lblTest))
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(154)
                        .addComponent(btnUpdate)))
                .addContainerGap(191, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(109)
                .addComponent(lblTest)
                .addGap(29)
                .addComponent(btnUpdate)
                .addContainerGap(86, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);
}
}
```

**Change.java**

```
public class Change extends BluePrint
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Change obj = new Change();
    obj.create();
}

public void create()
{
    initialize();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    btnUpdate.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
        {
            NewText ntObj = new NewText();
            ntObj.setNewText();
        }
    });
}
}
```

**NewText.java**

```
public class NewText 
{
Change cObj = new Change();

public void setNewText()
{
    cObj.lblTest.setText("Updated");
}
}
```

Comment: There are two Change objects, one created in main and another one in NewText. One is visible, the other one just lurks in memory.

Comment: Thank you laune. Interesting. Whats the solution to this? How can I go about it

Comment: Pass the Change object through method create into the constructor of NewText.

Comment: Thanks laune. Managed to resolve it. As long as the same object is used, it seems to work. Thanks a lot!